# Can I use both test and production connections strings in the Azure function connection strings section?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions

I have this Azure function below and it has some static variables that pull from the connnection strings section in my Azure function settings.
From the code below you can see that I'm pulling just one connection string for each key and/or database. Each correlate to a value in my Azure function settings area as seen in the picture below.

But now I want to be able to designate a test string and a production string!
How can I do this without going into the Azure settings and manually changing the hidden string values? Should I use pre processor statements like #if DEBUG

```
namespace Yogabandy2017.StripeWebhook
{
public static class StripeWebhook
{
    static string YbDatabaseConnectionString;
    static string SendGridApiKey;
    static string StripeSecret;
    static string StripeApiKey; 

    static StripeWebhook()
    {
        SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName = typeof(SqlGeography).Assembly.FullName;
        YbDatabaseConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YogaBandyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        SendGridApiKey = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SendGridApiKey"].ConnectionString;
        StripeSecret = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StripeSecret"].ConnectionString;
        StripeApiKey = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StripeApiKey"].ConnectionString;
    }

    [FunctionName("StripeWebhook")]
    public static async Task<object> Run([HttpTrigger(WebHookType = "genericJson")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
        {
            greeting = $"Everythings ok!"
        });
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note the prompt

> Connection strings should only be used with a function app if you are using entity framework. For other scenarios use App Settings.

Even if your code works as well, my suggestion is to add keys in `Application settings` section above `Connection strings`, with  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingName"]` to read.

As for your question, consider using [slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots)(preview feature for function).

1. Create a test slot, it copies settings from production slot by default. Modify settings as needed.

   [image]
2. Fix settings as [slot settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped)(Both test and production slot). 
   [image]
3. After tests in test slot, swap two slots to consume the production settings. 
   [image]

If you don't want to work with slots, add both test and production settings with a different prefix(e.g. `test_SendGridApiKey` and `prod_SendGridApiKey`) to Application settings. Then add an extra `prefix` setting to determine which keys to read, of course we need to modify `prefix` manually.

For example, add three settings, two keys: `test_SendGridApiKey` and `prod_SendGridApiKey`, and one `prefix` with value `test`.

Then in function code, we call code below to get test keys

```
var prefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prefix"];
var settingName = "SendGridApiKey";
var sendGridApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[$"{prefix}_{settingName}"]`;
```

Once we change `prefix` to `prod` in Application settings, we get production keys.

Comment: thanks Jerry. As I'm unfamiliar with slots. I read the slots page but still don't know if I should use them.  One question, I have about 6 Azure functions, a web app, and a sql db. Plus a few other services that I'm calling/using like some Azure service buses to pass data to different Azure functions based on a timestamp. Right now I have one of everything (website, db, Azure functions), but before I go live I would like to create mirrors of everything to create (to have as a test environment) should I have all my Azure functions replicated for testing purposes?

Comment: @user1186050 If your Azure functions are not required to be live while you do tests, you could deploy to test slot and leave the production slot empty. Once test is finished, swapping, test slot is empty and production is live. Otherwise just duplicate for convenience and backup.

Comment: Hi Jerry. What do you mean by add an extra 'prefix' setting to determine which keys ti read?

Comment: @user1186050 Adding an app setting `prefix` with value `test` or `prod`(change manually). In function code, use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[$"{prefix}_{settingName}"]` to read.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for so many questions, could you provide a better example? I understand that I should put the two keys (test/production) in the app setting area in Azure, but then in the function code where I call it ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[$"{prefix}_{settingName}"] how exactly does this work? Also what ever happened to pre processor statements? Back in the day I used to use them, is that not the case anymore?

Comment: oh I see what you're doing, so I still have to manually change the prefix in the app settings to test/prod every time I publish the functions to production, right? I'm curious now, wondering if this is the best solution? Like I said in the original post, I have a web app, db, Azure functions and service buses all running for this one website. I want to have a mirror image of everything for testing and possibly backup! I know I can create a mirror of the db's, but now sure about the functions or service buses. Do you have any other ideas or knowledge about that?

Comment: @user1186050 Correct. Sorry that I am not sure if it's the best or not, but propose a possible solution I could offer for now if slot is not your choice.  As for the mirror problem, if geographical location is not a concern, simply using solt or creating another Function app are both ok. Not familiar with Service bus so more suggestion.